# Composing Action in Play Java

Tags: java, playframework

I know we have same types of questions in Stackoverflow, but to my best knowledge these are all written in Scala.
In [the official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition), you can see how to compose Action.
Actually I am not clear of it, but

```
public class VerboseAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {
public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) {
    Logger.info("Calling action for {}", ctx);
    return delegate.call(ctx);
}
```

This above code is same with a below one?

```
@With(VerboseAction.class)

public Result verboseIndex() {
    return ok("It works!"); }
```

And they write we have to delegate to the wrapped Action, but in above code which action is called?
What does `delegate.call(ctx)` mean?
I know Play's Action is an instance of `Action`, but the return value is actually `CompletionStage<Result>`, not `Action`.
So, I am confused.   Maybe I have tiny misunderstandings, so could anyone point out it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer question by question:

This above code is same with a below one?

No, its actually composing both actions with "with" annotation.

but in above code which action is called?

Action is process of serving response to request received. 
This action will be called whenever a request to this method receive (request are mapped to methods in routes file).

And they write we have to delegate to the wrapped Action,
What does delegate.call(ctx) mean?

delegate is:

```
/**
 * The wrapped action.
 */
"public Action<?> delegate;"
```

and call is:

```
/**
 * Executes this action with the given HTTP context and returns the result.
 */
"public abstract Promise<Result> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable"
```

in Action class.
so delegate.call means that wrap parametes in action and return result.

I know Play's Action is an instance of Action, but the return value is actually CompletionStage, not Action.

CompletionStage is actually is: "public interface CompletionStage"
Its documentation describes it:

> A stage of a possibly asynchronous computation, that performs an
>    action or computes a value when another CompletionStage completes.
>    A stage completes upon termination of its computation, but this may
>    in turn trigger other dependent stages.  The functionality defined
>    in this interface takes only a few basic forms, which expand out to
>    a larger set of methods to capture a range of usage styles:
>
> The computation performed by a stage may be expressed as a
>    Function, Consumer, or Runnable (using methods with names including
>    *apply*, *accept*, or *run*, respectively)
>    depending on whether it requires arguments and/or produces results.
>    For example, {@code stage.thenApply(x -> square(x)).thenAccept(x ->
>    System.out.print(x)).thenRun(() -> System.out.println())}. An
>    additional form (*compose*) applies functions of stages
>    themselves, rather than their results.

This

> "A stage of a possibly asynchronous computation, that performs an action or 
>   computes a value when another CompletionStage completes."

and

> "The computation performed by a stage may be expressed as a Function, 
>   Consumer, or Runnable"

Clears that it is function, Consumer, or Runnable that performs some computation. You are actually composing actions and returning

```
return ok("It works!");
```

not CompletionStage.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer!   But although you gave me vast amount of information, but they don't link in myself.     What does the first code intend?

Comment: Its description of delegate and call, delegate is field in Action class and call is method of Action class.

Comment: Now I almost grasp the whole picture by combining other my question. In my question, what does `delegate.call(ctx)` do?  You have explained `delegate` is the field of the Action class and `call` is the method which returns `Promise<Result> which can be `Result` soon. So, what does it actually do?

Comment: Clearly mentioned in method docs "Executes this action with the given HTTP context and returns the result.". 
To get picture clear, go through code by debugger and also read documentation for every class used here.

Answer (score 0):

An `Action` is a unit of work that provides a `Result` (in the end). Your first block of code constructs an `Action` that will execute the log statement, and then return with a call to the `delegate`, which will be the next `Action` unit (either another annotation or the controller method) to execute and calls that, passing the context along the entire time.

Your misunderstanding in the last part of the question is that the return type of the call is not the next `Action` to undertake. It is the (eventual) `Result` of all the `Action`s.

Comment: Well, in your explanation `Action` is a working unit. So, in the sense `call(Http.Context ctx)` is similar to `delegate.call(ctx)` because both is `Action`?  What is the exactly `delegate`? Is it Play's internal class related to `Controller`?    And assuming from your answer, the instance that can be `Result` finally is `CompletionStage<Result>`?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita `delegate` is the next `Action` and is set by Play before it invokes the `call` method. `delegate.call(ctx)` invokes the next `Action` with the context.

Comment: The return value of `delegate.call(ctx)` is `Promise<Result>`, not `Action`.  How do you explain it?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita Because an invocation on a method results in the result of that method. The delegate itself is an Action. An Actions call method returns a promise of a Result. Look at your own codes return type. Why do you expect the next Action to return anything different?

Comment: @KayuzaTomita The last Action is a wrapper around your Controller method, which will return the final Result.